# Risch algorithm analogue for differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, closed-form

I know that we can determine whether an integral has closed form, that is, is a composition of elementary functions. That problem is (more or less) solved by [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). For differential equation solutions we consider a bit weaker condition, a solution can contain integrals of elementary functions.

Is there an algorithm which decides if solution can be expressed like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. see this Wikipedia link (and some more characters to be on the safe side): https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Picard%E2%80%93Vessiot_theory