# Existence of closed form solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a solution of an ODE
$$y''+4yy'+y^3=0.$$
I tried several standard strategies but could not come out with any result. Numerical calculation gives somewhat converging solution (depends on the initial value) $y\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$, but this is the best I can tell. Now I started to suspect if there is no closed form expression for the solutions of this ODE. Is there any way to show/disprove if there is a closed form solution to this ODE?

Comment: Based on a quick Wolfram search, there is no closed form, but it is possible to find a series expansion of the differential equation. There is also a [“Risch Algorithm for differential equations”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673711/risch-algorithm-analogue-for-differential-equations)

Comment: Even if you can't find an explicit formula, you could try writing the ODE as a first-order system by letting $z=y'$ and studying the phase portrait in the $yz$-plane to get information about the solutions.

Comment: Resurgence theory and transseries will produce solutions

Comment: @NickCastillo Can you elaborate?

Comment: I will try and write a solution later

Comment: I can't write a full answer right now, but if you do as I suggested above, and then let $w=y^2$, you get a system which up to a rescaling of the vector field (= up to time reparametrization) is **linear**, so you'll be able to say exactly what the trajectories in the upper $zw$-plane look like, and hence in the $zy$-plane too, even though it might not be possible to get a closed-form expression for how quickly they are traversed. If I'm not mistaken, $y$ will tend to zero iff you start at a point where $y' \ge -(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}) y^2$, otherwise it tends to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking $y’=y^2p(y)$ and $y=e^{\xi}$ we arrive at
\begin{equation}
pp’_{\xi}+2p^2+4p+1=0,
\end{equation}
which is separable. After integration and rearranging you’ll get that
\begin{align}
1=cy\left(2p+\sqrt 2+2\right)^{(1+\sqrt 2)/4}\left(-2p+\sqrt 2-2\right)^{1-\sqrt 2}.
\end{align}
Now I’ll take $y=1/u$, giving the equation
\begin{align}
u=c\left(-2u’_x+\sqrt 2+2\right)^{(1+\sqrt 2)/4}\left(2u’_x+\sqrt 2-2\right)^{1-\sqrt 2}.
\end{align}
For equations of the form
\begin{align}
u=F(u’)
\end{align}
the solution is given via the method of integration by differentiation in “Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations” 2ed. by Polyanin and Zaitsev implicitly as
\begin{align}
u=F(s), \quad x=\int\frac{F(s)’}{s} \mathrm ds+c,
\end{align}

which is not difficult to show.

Your equation has the  implicit solution

\begin{align}
y&=\frac{1}{c}\left(-2s+\sqrt 2+2\right)^{(-1-\sqrt 2)/4}\left(2s+\sqrt 2-2\right)^{-1+\sqrt 2},\\
x&=\int \frac{c}{s}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds} \left[\left(-2s+\sqrt 2+2\right)^{(1+\sqrt 2)/4}\left(2s+\sqrt 2-2\right)^{1-\sqrt 2}\right]\mathrm ds+c_2.
\end{align}
If I’m inputting the integral correctly in Wolframalpha it has a fairly long solution involving Hypergeometric functions, which I will leave for you to get. An implicit solution is more than one can usually ask for!

Comment: Maple give the same answer as yours. Maple code: `dsolve(diff(y(x), x, x) + 4*y(x)*diff(y(x), x) + y(x)^3 = 0, y(x), parametric);
value(subs([_T = t, _C2 = c2, _C1 = c1], %));
simplify(convert(%, ln));` in paramteric form. :)

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk You could have saved me some effort! Just kidding of course, I’ll take any excuse to solve an ODE.

Comment: This sounds legit. Thanks for your effort. As you pointed out, this looks like involving hypergeometric function, so it is fare say this is not elementary in my notion (after provoking the obvious uniqueness). I got this problem from my friend, which happened in an undergrad 2nd year ODE exam to "solve" the given ODE. I am doubtful if anyone could actually give the solution. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give you an idea of the problem you face with $$y''+4yy'+y^3=0$$ switch variables and write the equation as
$$-\frac {x''}{[x']^3}+4\frac y{x'}+y^3=0$$ Using $p=x'$
$$-\frac {p'}{p^3}+4\frac y{p}+y^3=0$$ This on can be integrated but it leads to the implicit equation
$$2 \sqrt{2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{y^2 p+2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\log \left(1+\frac{4 y^2   p+2}{y^4 p^2}\right)=4\log{y}+C$$

No way to recover $p=???$ but this form could be useful for a numerical integration.

Comment: You’ve made an error after taking $p=x’$. You should get $-p’/p^2$ which you’ll find allows a nicer solution!

Comment: @Eli: No, $p(y)=x'(y)$ simply gives $p'(y)=x''(y)$, so $-x''(y)/x'(y)^3 = -p'(y)/p(y)^3$ is correct.

Comment: @HansLundmark Whoops you’re correct!